# post-save case in node api?

Tags: 6, nodes

Is there such thing as a post-save type of case in the node_api function or any other type of function? This question is in reference to a question I posted [What operation should I use to write node's information in an email when the node is saved?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/what-operation-should-i-use-to-write-nodes-information-in-an-email-when-the-nod)

I want to be able to have something happen after pressing the save button, but AFTER the saving into the database has been completed. I have tried 'update' and 'insert' and they don't seem to work.

EDIT: heres my code

```
case 'presave':
    {
        if(($node->type == 'team_practice_info') | ($node->type == 'schedule'))
        {

            if(!empty($node->field_alert[0]['value']))
            {
                if($node->field_alert[0]['value'] == 'on')
                {                       
                    //email out to everyone an email about the content change/update
                    $query = db_query("SELECT * 
                                       FROM {content_type_athletics_alert}
                                       JOIN {content_field_team}
                                       ON content_type_athletics_alert.nid = content_field_team.nid
                                       WHERE content_field_team.field_team_nid = 
                                            (SELECT field_team_nid
                                             FROM {node}
                                             JOIN {content_field_team}
                                             ON node.nid = content_field_team.nid
                                             WHERE node.nid = %d)", $node->nid);
                    $rows = array();
                    //db_fetch returns an array of the next row in the query
                    while ($row = db_fetch_array($query))
                    {                       
                        //pull out the email from the array, then send an email to each subscriber                          
                        $email = $row['field_email_address_value'];
                        $first_name = $row['field_first_name_value'];
                        $last_name = $row['field_last_name_value'];
                        $t_id = $row['field_team_nid'];
                        $t=node_load($t_id);
                        $sport = (current($t->taxonomy));
                        $team = $t->title.' '.$sport->name;

                        alert_message_mail_send($email, $first_name, $last_name, $team, $node);
                    }
                    //reset the alert checkbox to off
                    $node->field_alert[0]['value'] = 'off';
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

   break;
```

Comment: The 'insert' and 'update' `$op` work perfectly for me (and have done for a couple of years now), can you post the code you're using that doesn't work? To answer your question, no, there isn't a 'post-save' `$op`, as that is taken care of by 'insert' and 'update'

Comment: I've written a module that provides what you're looking for. You can find the details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308465/post-save-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having trouble with [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (though I have never had problems with it), you could try using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

There is a stock event **After saving new content** that you can try.  There is also a stock DO action, **Send a mail to a user**.  You then get the normalish token-based email form that you can configure.

We have used this on few projects with good luck.

Comment: Everyone is saying that they don't have any issues with node_api, there must be some way of fixing my problem without having to use a different module....

Answer (score 0):

Use the register_shutdown_function. Here's the code for drupal 7, modify it for drupal 6 as needed:

```
<?php

function your_module_node_update($node){    
    if($node->type == 'your_node'){
        register_shutdown_function('_your_module_send_report_email',$node);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: see drupal_register_shutdown_function