# how to write a post-save trigger

Tags: 6, nodes, rules

The node_api hook provides a bunch of triggers which allows you to customize what might happen on, for example, a presave. The node_api presave opcode triggers an action to occur after clicking on the node 'save' button but BEFORE the information in the node form is inserted into the database. I would like to create a trigger which will be a post-save trigger, to trigger my custom code after clicking the save button but AFTER the node info has been saved into the database. Does anyone have any ideas of how I might create such a trigger?

(I have read the documentation about how to create a trigger, I just don't know to code the trigger I am describing above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to break the process down a bit (based on your other questions:[1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/what-operation-should-i-use-to-write-nodes-information-in-an-email-when-the-nod),[2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30402/post-save-case-in-node-api)); when you submit a node form:

1. [`node_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/6) calls [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/6).
2. `node_save()` immediately calls `node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'presave');` to inform other modules about the presave.
3. `node_save()` then sets up a few properties on the node object, and the node record is written to the `node` table in the database using `drupal_write_record()`.
4. At the very, very end of the function (*after* the data has been written to the `node` table), `node_invoke_nodeapi()` is called again with either `'insert'` or `'update'`, depending on the current operation being run.

If you look through those functions, and the summary above, you'll see that the node data is 100%, definitely committed to the database **before** the `'insert'` or `'update'` operations are run for `hook_nodeapi()`.

If that's not happening for your installation I would strongly recommend replacing core with a fresh version, as it sounds like something's gone horribly wrong!

Getting to the actual question; the only way you can add a post-save hook is to add another line in the core `node_save()` function to invoke it. But you would be adding it immediately after the call to `node_invoke_nodeapi($node, $op);` (where `$op` is `'insert'` or `'update'`) anyway, so I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: I can't believe that my core is messed up since issue is happening on my personal copy of drupal as well as the the one I am working on (which is on a different server). I posted my code at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30402/post-save-case-in-node-api , do you see anything in the code which would create my issue?

Comment: Ah ok, so it's CCK stuff that's missing from the database when your insert/update `$op` is running. What's your module called? Is the first letter of it 'a' or 'b' by any chance?

Comment: yes, it starts with a, why would that make a difference?

Comment: Ohhh it does :) I'll answer one of your other questions, it'll make more sense in that context